# Infinite while loop in Python (finding prime number and GCD)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trapped by a infinite loop in my program and I really don't know what is the fault in it.

Here is my code:

```
from reference import brute_prime, euclid_gcd, extended_euclid

def rsa(min_p, min_q, min_e):

    p = brute_prime(min_p)
    q = brute_prime(min_q)

    n = p * q
    phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
    e_prime = brute_prime(min_e)

    while euclid_gcd(e_prime, phi) != 1:
        e_prime = brute_prime(min_e)
        print(e_prime)
        e_prime += 1
    return e_prime

    #d = extended_euclid(e_prime, phi)                
    #tup1 = (d, e_prime, n)    
    #return tup1
```

My aim here is to use `brute_prime` and `euclid_gcd` to find e, by iteratively finding the next smallest prime number `e_prime` using `brute_prime`, and testing whether `gcd(e′,ϕ)=1`. If successful, terminate, if not, increment `e_prime` and continue.

Note that these functions that I called are all imported and there is nothing wrong in the function. What is wrong?

EDIT:

When trying to see the result of each iteration I tried something like this

```
print(rsa(11, 13, 3))
```

And the loop gives me 3 every single time.

EDIT:
This is `brute_prime`

```
def brute_prime(number):
#Making sure that the input from number will be type int
#setting two convenient limits for future use in the loop
    number = int(number)
    point_begin = 2
    point_end = int((number**0.5)) + 1

    #Two specific exceptions in the function that will execute and ignores 
    #later commands so that it is a tiny bit more efficient...
    if number == 2: 
        return 2
    elif number == 1:
        return 1


    while True:
        condition = True
        for i in range(point_begin, point_end):
            if number % i == 0:
                condition = False
                break
        if condition:
            return number
        else:
            number += 1
```

EDIT: 
This is `Euclid_gcd`

```
def euclid_gcd(num1, num2):

    while num2:
        num1, num2 = num2, num1 % num2
    return int(num1)
```

Comment: while True is a typical infinite loop. True is never False by definition...

Comment: @JacquesGaudin But I did add a break in it right? The loop never reaches break?

Comment: what is  `euclid_gcd`?

Comment: this might take a while to compute. Have you tried with known value to see if e_prime went too high?

Comment: Thing is I tested different examples. And some of them work but some of them just makes this loop infinite and never returns a result. I tried to check by return the e_prime after the loop and it just gives me nothing

Comment: maybe because they haven't finished. If you know what value of e_prime you expect, print e_prime in everyloop and see if it stops at the right time. your code should work

Comment: please post full code for clarity

Comment: @HarryLens, you need to share  a working example of how it fails.

Comment: @HarryLens, we still don't know the definition of euclid_gcd or  e_prime  so still cannot run the code.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ah I see. Sorry. I will add that.

Comment: What does brute_prime calculate ?

Comment: @AtulVaibhav uses a very dumb way to find the prime number that is bigger than num and closest to num

Comment: `print(point_begin, point_end)` in the loop, you also don't use   `n = p * q`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm sorry I don't get it. Do you want me to print that in brute_prime to test it or something else? For the n I commented out my very last few lines since I dont really need to use them but n will be used in that extended_euclid which does not participate in my error I guess...

Comment: @HarryLens, the values never change

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thing is when I am doing that import I actually called a ready-to-go function that is already provided and tested to be good instead my version. So that makes me really confused....

Comment: When you get to  `point_begin == 2`  and `point_end == 3` you end up an an infinite loop

Comment: You need to catch that case, something along the lines of   `if point_end == 3:return 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108901/discussion-between-harry-lens-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: thanks, NB: 1 is not a prime, `if number == 1, return 2`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  `point_begin = 2` and `point_end = 3` will `not` be an infinite loop. You are talking about case when number is between 4 to 9, in these cases `brute_prime` will return `5 or 7 or 11`.

Comment: @Atuk Vaibhav,  the issue has been sorted in the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop in RSA function looks buggy as `min_e` is not being updated, so same value is used in each iteration thus the loop is stuck, check your logic.
or use this:

```
    while euclid_gcd(e_prime, phi) != 1:
            e_prime = brute_prime(min_e)
            min_e = e_prime + 1 # check for next prime-number co-prime to phi
```

Also note, 1 is **not prime**. For 1 as input, `brute_prime` should return `2`.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps unrelated, but why not do something like

```
e_prime = brute_prime(min_e)
#This loop will not calculate and return me e_prime.
#Instead it just keeps running and exits later with nothing.
while euclid_gcd(e_prime, phi) != 1:
    e_prime = brute_prime(min_e)
    e_prime += 1
return e_prime
```

Comment: I tried it in my code and it seems like nope. Python god did not gift me a result lol...